# OpenGL fade out/in not working

Tags: java, opengl, jogl

I'm trying to fade in/out an image using JOGL. I can render the image fine, however it is always rendered with full intensity. Below is the code:

```
private void render(GLAutoDrawable glad) {
GL2 gl = glad.getGL().getGL2();

// Prepares the rendering, things such as disabling depth, clearing the buffer bit etc
setUpGL(gl);

BufferedImage background = main.getCurrentState().getImage();
// Render the background, adapted from here: http://bit.ly/QjeusP
renderImage(gl, background, background.getWidth(), background.getHeight());

gl.glEnable(GL2.GL_BLEND);
gl.glBlendFunc(GL2.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL2.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
gl.glColor4f(0, 0, 0, alpha);
gl.glBegin(GL2.GL_QUADS);
gl.glVertex2f(0, background.getHeight());
gl.glVertex2f(background.getWidth(), background.getHeight());
gl.glVertex2f(background.getWidth(), 0);
gl.glVertex2f(0, 0);
gl.glEnd();
gl.glDisable(GL2.GL_BLEND);
}
```

the variable alpha is a float, which is incremented by 0.1 for each render, if it exceeds 1.0, it is decremented by 0.1 until it is less than 0, then incremented, and so on.

EDIT 1: Here is the code that updates the alpha value:

```
private void update() {
  if (isTransparent) {
    alpha += 0.1f;
    if (alpha >= 1.0f) {
      alpha = 1.0f;
      isTransparent = false;
    }
  }
  else {
    alpha -= 0.1f;
    if (alpha <= 0.0f) {
      alpha = 0.0f;
      isTransparent = true;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you should show the code of `renderImage` and the code that updates the `alpha` value? And what means *"it doesn't fade in"*? Is the image always rendered with full intensity?

Comment: @ChristianRau apologies, please see the edit

Comment: Where is `alpha` defined and used?

Comment: @DanW alpha is defined inside the same class `private float alpha` and is only modified inside the update method

Comment: Where do you call the `update` method from?

Comment: @DanW update is called from the overridden `display` method (overridden from GLEventListener)

Comment: If you use gl.glColor4f(0, 0, 0, 1); do you get the textured image, or an all black image?

Comment: @Michael the textured image, but it's grayer than usual

Answer (score 2):

It may be a depth testing issue. I don't know what `renderImage` does, but if it just renders a screen-aligned textured quad at `z = 0`, then the quad you render over it will not get rendered when depth testing is enabled, as it is at the same depth as the texture quad. So try to `glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)` while rendering your half-black quad (and `glEnable` it afterwards).

**EDIT:** Stupid thought, but could it be you're changing the alpha that fast so that you in the end only have a constant gray shade?

Comment: That was my first thought, however setUpGL contains the line `gl.glDisable(GL2.GL_DEPTH_TEST);`

Comment: I tried reducing the rate of alpha change, but it made no difference. The problem was elsewhere (see my answer)